# how save to state and save to local variable result from fetch api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a function that returns json:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    articleDetail: (id) => {
        return dispatch(articles.articleDetail(id));
    }
  }
};
```

I get the result of the call here:

```
class ArticleDetail extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        articleId: props.match.params.id,
        asd: "",
        art:{}
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.articleDetail(this.state.articleId).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.article);
        this.setState({art:res.article})
    });
    this.setState({asd: "asda"})
}
```

console.log(res.article) return me: **{id: 1, author: {…}, headline: "First test article", description: "sadasdsads", img_name: "D.png", …}**

but I can't write this result in state, just outside the function, as I did with asd.

I would appreciate it if you would help me, maybe there is some way to write the result of this.props.articleDetail () in state.

I also wanted to ask if I could write the result of calling this function into a variable, and the function returns promise

And also, is it possible to set some variable over this function and record what my console.log "returns" to my external variable.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: `but I can't write this result in state, just outside the function, as I did with asd.`
are you getting an error?

Comment: No, I just didn't get the change in state. 
I am just interested in these 3 operations that I have listed possibly using the syntax javascript

Comment: how do check if the state changed? is there some ui element attached to it? also, you can try changing you state change to    ```this.setState({ art: res.article }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.art);
        });``` so you can see if it changed or not

Comment: oh thanks, actually yes, the state is being updated, apparently I wrote console.log not there, I need to re-read the sequence again how the component is loaded

Comment: I understand correctly, so I can write the data from the api response into the variable declared above within this lifecycle function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how did you check if the state changed?
In order to properly check if the state has been updated apply a callback to the [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) function like this (remember that `setState` is async):

```
this.setState({ art: res.article }, () => {
    // this happens after the state has been updated
    console.log(this.state.art);
});
```

in regards to your comment about setting the state in the lifecycle methid then it's perfectly fine as long as you do it in `componentWillMount` and not in `componentDidMount`.